# Understand how to use backtick with notepad(MS)

Tags: powershell, notepad, backticks

if I do with powershell that

```
    [string]$text = "this `nis a `ntest"
    $text > c:\test.txt
```

with notepad++ this is the result:

```
    this
    is a
    test
```

but if I open it with notepad of windows it doesn't work:

```
    this is a test
```

why that? how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notepad exclusively uses Windows <kbd>CRLF</kbd> `EOL` markers. To get your line breaks to show in Notepad, use this:

```
`r`n
```

Reasonable text editors (read: almost everything but `notepad.exe` - I'm partial to Notepad++) handle all EOL styles properly - <kbd>CRLF</kbd>, <kbd>CR</kbd>, and <kbd>LF</kbd>.